# Convergence of Matrix Power Series

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If $A$ is a square matrix with complex entries, then $\| A\|$ is defined as the sum of the absolute values of the entries of $A$. I have shown that this matrix norm is homogeneous, subadditive, and submultiplicative.

Now, if we let $G(x)$ be a power series with complex coefficients, I want to show that $G(A)$ converges if $\|A\|$ is less than the radius of convergence of the power series.

My analysis is a bit rusty, so here's my handwavy reasoning: if we denote the $n$th partial sum of the power series by $G_n$, then $\| G_n(A)\|\leq G_n(\| A\|)$, by the properties of the matrix norm (I think). Then, the matrix norm of $G_n(A)$ will be bounded below by $0$ and bounded above by $G_n(\| A\|)$. But of course, this doesn't show that $G(A)$ converges.

How do I finish this argument? Maybe I could try to show that $G(A)-G_n(A)$ converges to the zero matrix, but I can't really take norms since $G(A)$ may not be a well defined matrix.

Comment: Try Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Oh, I see. Since, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there's an $N$ such that for all $m, n>N$, $|G_m(\|A\|)-G_n(\|A\|)|<\varepsilon$, this means that $\|G_m(A)-G_n(A)\|<\varepsilon$, so the sequence of matrix partial sums is also Cauchy. And since the space of matrices is just $\mathbb C^{n^2}$, it's complete, so all Cauchy sequences converge. Is this argument correct?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Actually there is a mistake.  You should really use $H_n(\|A\|)$ instead of $G_n(\|A\|)$, where the coefficients of the power series of $H$ are the absolute values of the coefficients of the power series of $G$.  That would apply to both your and my arguments.

Comment: Yeah, I was worrying about absolute convergence...is the radius of convergence defined by convergence or absolute convergence?

Comment: If $|x| < R$, where $R$ is the radius of convergence, then the power series for $G(x)$ is absolutely convergent.